# "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Tags: batch

I've developed a new feature for my Batch game which gives the user the ability to define the name of their own save file along with the loading system and the new saving system is working properly as of now.

However, during the testing of the new code the program gives a message 'The syntax of the command is incorrect.' and crashes.

```
:load2
cls
color E
echo Warning: Spaces not allowed!
set /p load2=File: 
set ext1=.sav   
set ext2=.bat
cls
echo Loading Save File...
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
if exist %load2%%ext1%
if not exist %load2%%ext1% goto :nosave
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
ren %load2%%ext1% %load2%%ext2%
call %load2%%ext2%
ren %load2%%ext2% %load2%%ext1%
cls
color A
echo Game loaded.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
if %saver%=player1 goto :p1sturn
if %saver%=player2 goto :p2sturn
```

Thanks for reading, everyone who participated will be added in the credits for assisting me in cod

Comment: Which line is the error on?  If you don't know comment out code until the very last line is the line with the error.

Comment: The error shows after the 'Loading Save File...' line.

Comment: `IF EXIST filename ` must be followed by a command. otherwise a syntax violation occurs.

Comment: The error appears after 'Loading Save File...' because that is the last thing echoed.  Please comment lines to narrow down where the error is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
==>if exist x
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

The error caused by `if exist %load2%%ext1%`. Remove it entirely: it's superabundant as followed by `if not exist %load2%%ext1% goto :nosave`

Another error:

```
==>if player1=player1 echo x
=player1 was unexpected at this time.
```

The right syntax (note quotes and doubled `=` equals sign):

```
if "%saver%"=="player1" goto :p1sturn
if "%saver%"=="player2" goto :p2sturn
```